# Displaying steps on the staircase problem

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to determine, how to display the individual different ways to climb to n level steps with a custom amount of intervals.

For example, If number of steps = 8 and the intervals are 2 and 3, I want the display to print out `{2,2,2,2}{2,3,3}{3,2,3}{3,3,2}`. I tried implementing a way to follow the recursive method, that I used to count the number of ways, but I don't even think I am on the right track for solving the problem.

```
int recursiveMethod(int n, vector<int> intervals, vector<int> &test, vector<int> &intervalsByStep)
{
    int count = 0;

    if (n < 0)
    {            //base case 1
        return 0;
    }

    if (n == 0)
    {           //base case 2
        intervalsByStep.insert(intervalsByStep.end(), test.begin(), test.end());
        for (int i = 0; i < intervalsByStep.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << intervalsByStep.at(i);
        } 

        cout << "\n";

        test.clear();
        return 1;
    }

    for (int element : intervals)
    {
        test.push_back(element);
        count += recursiveMethod(n - element, intervals, test, intervalsByStep);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Your code looks like it is on the right track to me, although I do see at least one problem related to the `test.clear()` line before it backtracks.  (Think about that... you might prefer to only remove the _last_ element in `test` there.) Anyway, it would be helpful if you tested it on some cases and included anything problematic here.

Comment: You're not asking a question. Also,  you don't even share your doubts about your code. Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, if you have issues with code, it helps if you provide a [mcve].

Comment: You're not asking a question. Also,  you don't even share your doubts about your code. Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, if you have issues with code, it helps if you provide a [mcve].

Comment: In that final loop, I think you need to take `element` out of `test` again for the next iteration.